# jQuery : Are events handlers removed from objects if they are removed from the DOM using html()

Tags: jquery, events, memory

I am concerned about memory leaks in my application as I use jquery's html() method a lot to replace content in the the DOM. **I just want to make sure that not of these event listeners are going to be hanging around in browser memory.**

I have searched the jquery docs with no clear answer. Does anyone know?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are.

If you use jQuerys `.html()` it will take care of you. Looking into the jQuery source, this line is getting called:

```
jQuery.cleanData( this[i].getElementsByTagName("*") );
```

which effectively cleans up all *data* and *events*. This of course won't work if you're overwritting a DOMnodes `innerHTML` property explicitly.

Comment: Ah great! Isn't jquery lovely :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems using bind in jQuery, you can have more control over the events and handlers such as in this example from http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

```
var myHandlers = {};    

myHandlers.handler = function() {
    alert('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
};
$('#foo').bind('click', handler);
$('#foo').unbind('click', handler);

delete(myHandlers.handler);
```

But I don't know if that is possible to control with the normal jQuery syntax of $('a').click() since all that is returned is a jQuery object and no references to the handlers or events.

There is related discussion to this question here on stack overflow:

[javascript memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316726/javascript-memory-leaks)