# Can I bind an event to the `remove()` method?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - Trigger event when an element is removed from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom)

What I want to do is run a particular section of code when a certain element is `remove()`d from the page using jquery.

Is there any way to attach an event listener onto removal of elements at all?

I ask because I am refactoring some code and there are a lot of places where this particular element is `remove()`d and it would be much easier (and useful) if I could just attach a function to an event call (if there is one?).

Thanks