# onmouseout not fired when element goes away

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a `mouseover` event which triggers a tooltip; I would like this tooltip to go away when the mouse is removed. `onmouseout` works well, *except* when the element goes away.

Here is a distilled example which uses background changes instead of tooltips (so you can easily run it):

```
<div id="bar">
  <div onmouseover="document.bgColor='gray'" onmouseout="document.bgColor='white'" style="border:1px solid black;">
   <span onclick="document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = ''">Remove me</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is this: when I click "Remove me", my mouse is no longer "over" the div, but the `onmouseout` doesn't trigger, because it has gone away. What I would like is for this example to revert to a white background when I click "Remove me".

There is an obvious solution, which I would like to avoid. I do not want the `onclick` handler which removes the element to manually "fix up" the document. This is because there may be arbitrarily many handlers which could remove the div with the `onmouseout`. In general, all of the `mouseout` and removal handlers may be generated dynamically, and need to know about each other. To complicate things further, I might have a case where removable elements are nested in each other, and any of them could be removed. (I might be able to remove this constraint, but it will take a little work.)

---

Here is an example of a solution that could work: on `mouseover`, register the modal dialogue as "active"; then whenever elements are removed, iterate over all modal dialogues and look for ones which are no longer in the document. But this requires me to keep a global store of dialogues, and takes time O(n*m), where n is the number of active dialogues, and m is how deeply nested the dialogue is in the DOM. Furthermore, I need to run this operation whenever I remove elements, even if it's pretty obvious nothing is affected.

Here is another solution that could work: if you can implement an `onremovedfromdocument` event, then we just copy the `onmouseout` handler to be the `onremovedfromdocument` event, and the example will work correctly too. (I hear jQuery might support this, but I need to interoperate with non-jQuery code.)

Here is yet another possible solution: have each modal dialogue repeatedly poll to see if its parent is in the document. When it is not, have it commit seppuku. But polling is really ugly. (I guess I'd be willing to do this if there's nothing better!)

Here's another idea: use event capture to allow the `onmouseout` element to capture the click element first, and setup a timer to check if it is still in the document after the click is done.

---

For reference, here is what I'm really trying to do: I have a JS widget which builds a complicated tree structure. Many of the edits to the widget involve clicking some button in the tree, which then adds or deletes from the tree (possibly deleting itself.) However, some of the nodes need more complicated edit procedures, so I would like to bring up a tooltip with instructions and possibly more buttons when the user mouses over them, or even keep the dialogue around if the user clicks them. But the user may change his mind and decide to delete the node, or any parent of the node, in which case the dialogue should go away.  You can view an implementation of what I currently have [here](http://logitext.ezyang.scripts.mit.edu/logitext.fcgi/proving/.28forall+x.2C+P.28x.29.29+.7C.2D+.28exists+x.2C+P.28x.29.29), where the dialogues are being manually created. I would like to start using a nice tooltip library, but all of them have the bug which I described above.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a closing `</a>` tag when you have no corresponding opening one?  Your span is also invalid html.  You need a closing span.

Comment: Your span continues to be invalid html.  <span /> doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

On modern browsers, there is the [`DOMNodeRemoved`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Events) event. So:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
div.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e){
    document.bgColor='white';
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HX88L/

The bad thing is, that event is already [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events). The replacement for the so-called [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events) doesn't look like it's ready to use yet. MDN doc page is still just a [stub](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers).

Comment: Nice! Do you know how modern the browser has to be? Edit: Re, deprecation, that sucks!

Comment: I read it works on IE9, Chrome and Firefox - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6987471/825789

Comment: Strangely enough, for whatever reason, in the full example this does not work. I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    <script>
    var liveToolTip = new Array();
    function addLiveToolTip(elName){
        if(elName in liveToolTip){
        }else{
            liveToolTip[elName]=1;}
    }
    function removeLiveToolTip(elName){
        if(elName in liveToolTip){
            delete liveToolTip[elName];
        }
    }
    function runOnMouseOuts() {
        for(mouseOut in liveToolTip) {
            document.getElementById(mouseOut).onmouseout();
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="bar">
  <div onmouseover="addLiveToolTip(this.id);document.bgColor='gray'" 
        onmouseout="removeLiveToolTip(this.id);document.bgColor='white'" style="border:1px solid black;" id="foo">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = '';runOnMouseOuts()">
      Remove me</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: This solution fails the modularity test. What if there were multiple onmouseout handlers inside bar?

Comment: I thought the onmouseoutevent being called was the hope. You can alternately just change the background color directly. Which I have edited it to do.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help matters, considering the background of the **document** is changed; not the contents of the `div` **bar**.

Comment: is this the behavior desired?

Comment: You're missing the point. The point is to do whatever onmouseout was in *any* of the active tooltips, w/o hardcoding one of them.

Comment: do you want to run all onmouseout events on all elements withing element "bar"?

Comment: Anything that has a mouse over it, yes. I might be able to be convinced that there will, in practice, only be one or two such elements active at any given time. But matters are complicated by the fact that I might want these tooltips to have HTML links in them, in which case they stick around longer than pure tooltips.

Comment: does this solution work for you or am I still missing something?