# Stack div boxes into two columns. But when box on the right is removed, all boxes after it should line up accordingly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have div boxes of identical heights and widths stacked up into two columns, like so:  [image]

Is it possible to make it behave in such a way that...when any of the boxes on the left is removed (using jQuery), the top-most box on the right will move the bottom spot on the left. So essentially, the boxes moving in the direction indicated by the pink arrow.

Comment: yes it is possible, it depends on your html and css

Comment: any leads i can look into as how to execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [remove event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom) and check it on your div box. And then append first element to another column

```
$('.yourDivBox').bind('remove', function() {
$('.secondColumn').first().appendTo('.firstColumn');
});
```

Something like this. Sorry I haven't time to check my code

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in CSS3, some browser might not support it! I've created an example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/swxn4/