# onRemove()-event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following situation: I'm storing dates in text-inputs and above those, the min- and maxdates are displayed. It is possible to add and remove additional inputs. The dates are stored in an array of objects `[{id: 1, val: '15.3.13'}, {id: 2, val: '1.4.13'}...]`
The onchange-event for these inputs now checks the array and calculates the minimum and maximum dates for display on the top of the page. But if I add an input, make it the minimum/maximum date and then remove it, the onchange-event isn't called.

Is there some kind of onremove-event for jQuery or do I have to work my way around and call everything manually?

(The scenario above is a highly simplified version of the real problem, just to get the idea of what I'm doing. Please don't just say "Why don't you call the onchange-method in the onclick-method of the button that removes the inputs?", because it's just not that easy ;-))

Comment: You should create a class/interface for your object, which handles such things for you. There are no `listeners` or `handlers` for native JavaScript objects.

Comment: I'm not trying to add a handler to the array itself, but to the DOM element (input) so that the input itself can delete the matching entry from the array. Sorry for the misunderstanding.
I already found a solution for my specific problem now, but it would be very interesting to know if there was such a thing as a "onremove"-event or something similar in jQuery though.

Comment: bind unbind? could you be looking for?

Comment: Nope, I'm not looking for unbinding events, I'm looking for an event that is triggered when the specified DOM-element is removed from the page.

Comment: there is a `DOMNodeRemoved` event, but browser support isn't wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this snippet? [jQuery - Trigger event when an element is removed from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom)

If not, please provide some code.

Answer (score -3):

You should use jquery's $.when() and .then()

```
    $.when($('#div').remove()).then(doAfterRemove());
```

Check out [this Fiddle to see it working](http://jsfiddle.net/VD73X/1/) to see it working.

Comment: this immediately removes the element, and immediately calls the doAfterRemove function.

Comment: I know. That is what Vince asked for. He said "I'm looking for an event that is triggered when the specified DOM-element is removed from the page." The doAfterRemove function can be passed an id which can then be used to update the array.

Comment: my point is that your code behaves identical to: `$('#div').remove(); doAfterRemove();` and such isn't a solution.

Comment: ok, i see your point now, my bad. I think you were right about the DOMNodeRemoved event, and I found a blog describing how to use this and improve browser support [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1623-Ask-Ben-Detecting-When-DOM-Elements-Have-Been-Removed-With-jQuery.htm).