# Mouseleave not triggered when element removed

Tags: jquery

### [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpenner/Sjt2u/)

**JavaScript**

```
$('#btn').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('#tt').show();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#tt').hide();
}).on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">press me</button>
<div id="tt">tooltip</div>
```

Basically, when you remove an element while your cursor is still over it, the `mouseleave` event is never triggered. I guess this makes sense because if the element is gone, the event/binding is gone too.

But how do we work around it?

Sure, I could put `$('#tt').hide();` in the `click` event too, but I was hoping for a more generic solution. My real-life example is a bit more complex and I don't always know when the element is going to be removed.

There's no `ondestroy` event or anything I can hook into, that will fire just before it's removed, is there?

Comment: How about triggering a mouseleave event http://jsfiddle.net/Sjt2u/1/

Comment: @Musa: That's pretty much identical to my point about adding something to the click handler... the element may be removed in various ways, I don't want to have to augment all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjt2u/2/) with the code from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10172676/1846192).

```
(function($){
  $.event.special.destroyed = {
    remove: function(o) {
      if (o.handler) {
        o.handler()
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery)

$('#btn').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('#tt').show();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('#tt').hide();
}).on('click', function() {
  $(this).remove();
}).on('destroyed', function() {
  $('#tt').hide();
})
```

Alternatively, you can bind to the DOMNodeRemoved mutation event, but the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeRemoved) states that this event type is deprecated [due to performance and cross browser support issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events).

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e) {
  if(e.target.id=='btn') {
    $('#tt').hide();
  }
});
```

In newer browsers (Chrome 18+, Firefox 14+) there is support for the [MutationObserver](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers) object, which is designed to replace mutation events. In your case it could work this way:

```
var target = document.querySelector('body');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {  
    if(mutation.removedNodes[0]!=undefined) {
      if(mutation.removedNodes[0].id=='btn') {
        $('#tt').hide();              
      }
    }
  });    
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

observer.observe(target, config);
```

Here's a [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18269/simple-dom-mutation-abstraction) to a question on Code Review where someone is writing a DOM MutationObserver shim which falls back on mutation events when the MutationObserver object isn't available.

Comment: That's a neat solution. Only works if the removal happens via the `.remove()` method though.

Comment: True, I have updated my answer with some alternative approaches which will work even when the element is removed in other ways.

Comment: `MutationObserver` looks pretty sweet. About time they add something like that :-)