# Durandal widget destory method or something equivalent

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I am setting some setInterval values on my widget's controller code as follows:

```
define(['durandal/widget'],function (widget) {
    var count = 0;
    var intervals = [],
        ctor = function (element, settings) {
               this.settings = settings;
        };

    ctor.prototype.updateCount = function( ){
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
            count = count + 1;
            return count;
            }, 1000);
            intervals.push(interval);
          }   
    return ctor;
}
```

The above code is being run inside a forEach loop inside the view like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: settings.items}">
 <span class="count" data-bind="text:$parent.updateCount()"></span>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is call the `clearInterval` method on all the items in the intervals array when the widget is destroyed or essentially removed from the dom. I know I could do this using the deactivate on a viewModel but from a reusability point of view, I would like the widget itself to handle the clearing of interval. Is there any way I could achieve this with the widget module in Durandal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the widget is removed with JQuery's "remove" function, adding a custom event handler on this "remove" function should go like this:

```
var self = this;
var self.count = 0;
var self.intervals = [];
self.ctor = function (element, settings) {
    $(element).on("remove", function () {
        $.each(self.intervals, function(index, ival) { 
            clearInterval(ival); 
        });
    });
    this.settings = settings;
};
```

The problem is that if the widget is removed without JQuery, simply by manipulating the DOM, the event will not be fired. You could then implement the code for the **DOMNodeRemoved** event, [but it's not gonna work for IE](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1623-Ask-Ben-Detecting-When-DOM-Elements-Have-Been-Removed-With-jQuery.htm)...

Edit: if you're using JQuery pre-1.9.1, you might want to check out the [other answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2200494/866172).

Comment: Hmm!! I will have to try this out and see if it actually solves the problem. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Yup listening to the "remove" event actually solves the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking into the same issue, there's a knockout way of achieving the same. Have a look at the following links https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/139 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/NqUkY-9us2g . The suggestion is to use:

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, callback)
```