# execute after jquery .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically have a button to delete something and the code is:

```
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
    //code here
    //$t is the item to delete
    $t.remove();
});
```

now I would like to execute the following code after the `remove` or `on` has finished:

```
if($('#bookmarks').is(':empty')){
    $('#bookmarks').css('visibility','hidden');
}
```

I tried adding this into the `.on`:

```
$t.on("remove", function () {
    if($('#bookmarks').is(':empty')){
        $('#bookmarks').css('visibility','hidden');
    }   
});
```

but that didn't work. So how can I execute that function after the item has fully been deleted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple, just execute it after you call `remove()`

```
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
    //code here
    //$t is the item to delete
    $t.remove();

    //remove done, next
    if($('#bookmarks').is(':empty')){
        $('#bookmarks').css('visibility','hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't believe none of the answers cache the query result : `var $bookmarks = $('#bookmarks');`

Comment: this worked...i'll accept it in 10 minutes when I AM allowed to

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){

$t.remove();

//remove done
if($('#bookmarks').is(':empty')){
    $('#bookmarks').hide();
}
```

});