# JavaScript: on element removed event listener

Tags: javascript, events, listener, element

What is the core javascript equivelent to the jquery's remove event listener

$(element).on('remove', someFunction);

Comment: Have you tried `element.addEventListener("remove", someFunction)`?

Comment: @LightStyle—you may need to [check the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener), there is no "remove" event.

Comment: @RobG, didn't check the spec because I hadn't time to do it. I simply guessed, and I was wrong. ;)

Comment: I actually found the following: `code` element.addEventListener("DOMNodeRemoved", someFunction); `code`

Comment: An update to this answer that does use Remove is available here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such event as `remove`, either as a DOM standard event or as a jQuery extension. Your example does nothing.

You will be able to use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to look for `removedNodes` in the future, but [browser support](http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver) isn't there yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it with a Mutation Observer:

```js
function onElementRemoved(element, callback) {
  new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if(!document.body.contains(element)) {
      callback();
      this.disconnect();
    }
  }).observe(element.parentElement, {childList: true});
}

// Example usage: 
onElementRemoved(yourElement, function() {
  console.log("yourElement was removed!");
});
```