# How to block .remove() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script for my client that already has some **encrypted JavaScript**. Somewhere in **encrypted JavaScript** there is `.remove()` event that trigger with a particular button. I found a script [jQuery - Trigger event when an element is removed from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom#answer-10172676) that detect the `.remove()` event. After that i tried to block that event with this:

```
$('#fileElem').on('destroyed', function(){
    $('#fileElem').die('remove');                            
    $('input[name="done_upload"]').trigger('click');
});
```

But i got `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'die'` might be the `destroyed` event trigger after `.remove()` action, I am not sure. And as i used to auto trigger the button with `$('input[name="done_upload"]').trigger('click');` not working because i got error before trigger event.

Can anyone help me to stop removing DOM element?

Comment: I seems to me that...once the destroyed event gets fired, the element is already gone so it's no use to intercept?

Comment: you can decode javascript by using this URL: jsbeautifier.org

Comment: @Baszz is there any alternative way?

Comment: What is the event that calls `remove()`, a `click`? Why not unbind the event and bind your own.

Comment: @jogesh_pi What I can think of is to add your own click handler to the same button and cancel out all others. But not sure if it works since that event can come later.

Comment: @Boaz yes `click` event call .remove() and i am working with same `click()' event but separately

Comment: you could clone the element and then reattach the clone after the click

Comment: What about changing the ID of the particular button? Anyone wants to remove it, will fail silently.

Answer (score 4):

[`.die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) is filed under the [removed section of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/removed/), so *unless* if you are using an older version of jQuery (like <1.8), it doesn't exist anymore. That's what's causing that thrown error.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfU7S/) (loaded with 1.9) alerts `false` while testing for `.die()`, which means it does not exist. If you use 1.8.3 or earlier though, it will alert true which means it's still there.

If you want to prevent the removal of that element, I suggest you "hijack" (replace) the button's click handler instead.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that he can refer to the element as `$(this)` inside the event handler, as it may no longer be accessible via DOM parsing (unlikely, I know, but worth him knowing).

Comment: @Archer but a jQuery object, regardless if it has fetched anything on the DOM, will still have it's prototype functions. Doing `$('#foo').remove().die().off()` with no `#foo` existing will not throw an error.

Comment: Yeah, but it may not return anything is my point, whereas `this` will still be a reference to the object.  Like I said, it's unlikely, but there's really no harm in explaining the use of `this` to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `destroyed` event is fired when element **is already destroyed** so you get an empty jQuery query result.