# Is there a JavaScript rich text editor with many change event handling capabilities?

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, ace-editor

I'm searching for a JavaScript richt text editor which supports event handling for events such as insertText, removeText or moveText (when somebody drags text from one place to another).

It's really difficult to find such an editor: For example, it was easy to implement a moveText event to the ACE editor - but unfortunately it only supports syntax highlighting and no custom formatting of a specified selection (as far as I know).

Other richt text editors weren't implemented on a way which would allow implementing a moveText event or just didn't have any change events.

Do you know such an editor or can help me in another way?

Cheers,
bloxx

Comment: you can still capture normal DOM events on a contenteditable region, stuff like dragstart, DOM Mutations, onpaste(), etc...

Comment: That's right - I already tried DOM Mutations - but how should I detect a "moveText" event when text of the editor is dragged to another place in the editor? This difference is important for my use case. dragstart is an idea. Thanks, I will try it...

Comment: dragstart should cover you, but i also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom which should let you detect the removed text as well...