# Is there something like "listenTo" in jQuery? Or do I have to use namespaces and manually unbind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using a third-party lazyload plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

In its source, it has the following:

```
if (0 === settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
    $container.on(settings.event, function (event) {
        return update();
    });
}
```

This applies a 'scroll' event to the parent element. There's no logic in the plugin for unbinding the event. This sucks because sometimes I will add 100s lazy elements and then remove and re-add others without replacing the container. This causes tons of events to stack up!

I'm considering modifying the plugin to read something like:

```
if (0 === settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
    //  .on('scroll.item_12')
    $container.on(settings.event + settings.namespace, function (event) {
        return update();
    });

    //  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom
    $(this).on('remove', function() {
        $container.off(settings.event + settings.namespace);
    });
}
```

Is this the correct way of handling such a scenario? When working with BackboneJS I have access to: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo, but I'm not certain that a similiar function exists in just jQuery/Javascript

Comment: I've namespaced events in jQuery like this: `scroll.left`/`scroll.right`, etc.

Comment: No, but you can implement this method in your own. And this is quite easy -  https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L221, https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L157

Comment: Even backbone using jquery `event.namespace` to handle DOM events.

No there is nothing like `listenTo` in jquery, but you could implement, using event.namespace is better and easier! (Even with implementing listenTo for jquery you must use a unique id for namespacing with `event.namespace`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jQuery you only have two methods; `on` and `off`. Or simply call remove() on each element that you're trying to get rid of.

```
$(document).off(elementName)
```