# Event handler for delete child component in AEM/CQ

Tags: aem

How can I add an event handler for my Adobe AEM6 component that triggers when a child component is deleted?

There are several listeners that I can attach event handlers to, listed in the [documentation for cq:listeners](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html#cq:listeners) but unfortunately there isn't one for afterchilddelete.

I've tried adding a cq:childEditConfig node to the component but, at least in AEM6, the handler doesn't fire:

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:listeners
        jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afterdelete="mynamespace.afterchilddelete"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: What does your handler do? Does it have to be on the client? An alternative would be an javax.jcr.observation.EventListener in your Java code.

Comment: I want to rerender the parent component, client side, when a child component is deleted, as an 'empty' component looks different to one with child components

Comment: Have you tried to add the afterdelete listener to the child components editConfig? Maybe you'll need to use the beforedelete if you need a reference to the deleted child. Or even a refresh the whole page to be sure the parent renders correctly.

Comment: unfortunately the child component can be any component, so I would have to add an afterdelete listener for every component in the site

Comment: ok, that is a valid point. Maybe you could use something out of AEm, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom