# Is there a way to run a function once an Event Listener is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to run a function once an element has been deleted from the html.

I added

```
$("selector").on('DOMNodeRemoved',function(){
            //do stuff
        });`
```

The issue is that while the function in running the element that has been deleted is still there, and is only removed after the function finishes running. Is there a way to run this function after this listener has completed?

Comment: This could be related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom

Answer (score 0):

could add a short `setTimeout` so code gets run at end of the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

```
$("selector").on('DOMNodeRemoved',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      //do stuff
    },10);               
});
```