# Event not working when an element is removed from html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events

I am trying to delete a row in database when an `a` element is removed, with backspace, delete key... But this event is never fired. Also, is it possible in any way to save the id just before it is removed?

```
$('a').on('remove', function () {
    var aId = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url:'/annotations/' + aId,
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': csrf_token},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: " + response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            console.log("ERROR: " + msg);
        },

    });
});
```

Comment: There is no `remove` event, unless you're triggering it manually? How are the `a` elements being removed from the DOM? More clarity is needed in your question

Comment: So how is this answer correct? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16225393/7170324

Comment: That's using jQueryUI, not plain jQuery.